# Is there any reason to sanitize user input to prevent them from cross site scripting themself?

Tags: xss

If I have fields that will only ever be displayed to the user that enters them, is there any reason to sanitize them against cross-site scripting?

Edit: So the consensus is clear, that it should be sanitized.  What I'm trying to understand is why?  If the only user that can ever view the script they insert into the site is the user himself, then the only thing he can do is execute the script himself, which he could already do without my site being involved.  What's the threat vector here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically: no. If you are sure that only they will ever see this page, then let them script whatever they want.

The problem is that there are a lot of ways in which they can make other people view that page, ways you do not control. They might even open the page on a coworker's computer and have them look at it. It is undeniably an extra attack vector.

Example: a pastebin without persistent storage; you post, you get the result, that's it. A script can be inserted that inconspicuously adds a "donate" button to link to your PayPal account. Put it up on enough people's computer, hope someone donates, ...

I agree that this is not the most shocking and realistic of examples. However, once you have to defend a security-related decision with "that is possible but it does not sound *too* bad," you know you crossed a certain line.

Otherwise, I do not agree with answers like "never trust user input." That statement is meaningless without context. The point is how to define user input, which was the entire question. Trust how, semantically? Syntactically? To what level; just size? Proper HTML? 
Subset of unicode characters? The answer depends on the situation. A bare webserver "does not trust user input" but plenty of sites get hacked today, because the boundaries of "user input" depend on your perspective.

Bottom line: avoid allowing anybody any influence over your product unless it is clear to a sleepy, non-technical consumer what and who.

That rules out almost all JS and HTML from the get-go.

P.S.: In my opinion, the OP deserves credit for asking this question in the first place. "Do not trust your users" is not the golden rule of software development. It is a bad rule of thumb because it is too destructive; it detracts from the subtleties in defining the frontier of acceptable interaction between your product and the outside world. It sounds like the end of a brainstorm, while it should start one.

At its core, software development is about creating a clear interface to and from your application. Everything within that interface is Implementation, everything outside it is Security. Making a program do the things you want it to is so preoccupying one easily forgets about making it not do anything else.

Picture the application you are trying to build as a beautiful picture or photo. With software, you try to approximate that image. You use a spec as a sketch, so already here, the more sloppy your spec, the more blurry your sketch. The outline of your ideal application is razor thin, though! You try to recreate that image with code. Carefully you fill the outline of your sketch. At the core, this is easy. Use wide brushes: blurry sketch or not, this part clearly needs coloring. At the edges, it gets more subtle. This is when you realize your sketch is not perfect. If you go too far, your program starts doing things that you do not want it to, and some of those could be very bad.

When you see a blurry line, you can do two things: look closer at your ideal image and try to refine your sketch, or just stop coloring. If you do the latter, chances are you will not go too far. But you will also make only a rough approximation of your ideal program, at best. And you could still accidentally cross the line anyway! Simply because you are not sure where it is.

You have my blessing in looking closer at that blurry line and trying to redefine it. The closer you get to the edge, the more certain you are where it is, and the less likely you are to cross it.

Anyway, in my opinion, this question was not one of security, but one of design: what are the boundaries of your application, and how does your implementation reflect them?

If "never trust user input" is the answer, your sketch is blurry.

(and if you don't agree: what if OP works for "testxsshere.com"? boom! check-mate.)

(somebody should register testxsshere.com)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you don't display a field to someone, doesn't mean that a potential Black Hat doesn't know that they're there.  If you have a potential attack vector in your system, plug the hole.  It's going to be really hard to explain to your employer why you didn't if it's ever exploited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this question has been answered entirely. He wants to see an accuall XSS attack if the user can only attack himself. This is actually done by a combination of CSRF and XSS.

With CSRF you can make a user make a request with your payload. So if a user can attack himself using XSS, you can make him attack himself (make him make a request with your XSS).

A quote from [The Web Application
Hacker’s Handbook](http://amzn.to/12xckJM):

> COMMON MYTH:
>
> “We’re not worried about that low-risk XSS bug. A user could exploit it only to attack himself.”
>
> Even apparently low-risk vulnerabilities can, under the right circumstances, pave the way for a devastating attack. Taking a defense-in-depth approach to security entails removing every known vulnerability, however insignificant it may seem. The authors have even used XSS to place file browser dialogs or ActiveX controls into the page response, helping to break out of a kiosk-mode system bound to a target web application. Always assume that an attacker will be more imaginative than you in devising ways to exploit minor bugs!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, always sanitize user input:

1. Never trust user input
2. It does not take a lot of effort to do so.

The key point being **1**.

Answer (score 0):

If the script, or service, that the form submits the values to is available via the internet then anyone, anywhere, can write a script that will submit values to it. So: **yes**, sanitize all inputs received.

The most basic model of web-security is pretty simple:

> **Do not trust your users**

It's also worth linking to my answer in another post ([Steps to become web-security savvy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704333/steps-to-become-web-security-savvy/1705146#1705146)): [[Steps to become web security savvy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704333/steps-to-become-web-security-savvy/1705146#1705146)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704333/steps-to-become-web-security-savvy/1705146#1705146).

I can't believe I answered without referring to the title-question:

> Is there any reason to sanitize user input to prevent them from cross site scripting themself?

You're *not* preventing the *user*'s being cross-site scripted, you're protecting your site (or, more importantly, you're *client*'s site) from being the victim of cross-site scripting. If you don't close known security holes because you couldn't be bothered it will become very hard to get repeat business. Or good word-of-mouth advertising and recommendation from previous clients.

Think of it less as protecting your client, think of it -if it helps- as **protecting your business**.